# How to get wmi providers registered in the system

Tags: windows, powershell, wmi

I Want to know/get all the wmi providers registered in a system.

Can i get using powershell command?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function Get-Providers ($ns="root") {
   Get-WmiObject -Namespace $ns -Class "__NAMESPACE" |
   foreach {
       Get-WmiObject -NameSpace $currNameSpace -Class __Win32Provider | select @{n="Namespace";e=    {$("$ns\" + $_.Name)}},@{n="Provider";e={$_.Name}}
       Get-Providers $("$ns\" + $_.Name) 
   } 
}
```

Comment: The recursive invocation of Get-Providers needs to be removed. I edited the post, but my edit has to be peer reviewed.

Comment: @dcaswell I don't think the answer is wrong, it just has a bug in it. With the edit the script works.

Comment: does it gives only win32 providers or all providers registered?

Comment: the code had some bugs that I have fixed now. It retrieves recursively all Win32Providers within the root namespace.

Answer (score 3):

you can get a list of all WMI Classes in powershell..

```
Get-WmiObject –List
```

Hope that helps !!!!

Comment: i want wmi providers registered..i guess -list  gives classes..thanks